# How can I find all results with a null foreign key in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, join

I have 2 tables... `meat` and `potatoes` in MySQL.

`meat_id` is the primary key for the `meat` table and there is a `meat_id` in the `potatoes` table that links the 2 tables. I want to find all rows in the `potatoes` table that don't have a valid `meat_id`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Using LEFT JOIN/IS NULL:

```
   SELECT p.*
     FROM POTATOES p
LEFT JOIN MEAT m ON m.meat_id = p.meat_id
    WHERE m.meat_id IS NULL
```

### Using NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM POTATOES p
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                    FROM MEAT m
                   WHERE m.meat_id = p.meat_id)
```

### Using NOT IN:

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM POTATOES p
 WHERE p.meat_id NOT IN (SELECT m.meat_id
                           FROM MEAT m)
```

### Summary

[LEFT JOIN/IS NULL is the best performing option if the column(s) compared in the join can not be NULL](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/).  If those values [***can be NULL***, then NOT EXISTS or NOT IN perform best](http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/).

Comment: I don't think this will work with a WHERE clause because the constraint is executed before the JOIN. Look at my answer, it uses `HAVING` instead.

Comment: @ShlaWiener: See the links I posted - MySQL is the only DB (of the major ones) where LEFT JOIN/IS NULL is the best performer (**only** when the columns compared in the join are **not** nullable).

Comment: Interesting, I always believed that mysql will look at the actual values from the db but I just verified that `WHERE` works. Using `HAVING` leads to the same result but can't perform better than where.

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT *
 FROM potatoes p
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from meat m where m.meat_id = p.meat_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a left join and use having:

```
SELECT p.potato_id, m.meat_id
FROM potatos p
LEFT JOIN meat m ON p.meat_id = m.meat_id
HAVING m.meat_id IS null
```

Comment: `HAVING` is only necessary if you're using aggregate functions - which your answer doesn't.  That's because the `HAVING` clause is equivalent to the WHERE, but the difference is that WHERE can not have aggregate functions (in subqueries is OK) while HAVING can.